# Undefined operation

Tags: c, mingw, codeblocks, undefined-behavior

I was fiddling with Code Blocks today and got a curious warning message. It was not an error, and it compiled and run with expected result, but the warning message picked my curiosity.

Code:

```
while (i < right)
    *(array + i) = *(buffer - left + i++);
```

and

```
while (i >= 0 && *(array + i) > key)
        *(array + i + 1) = *(array + i--);
```

got me error messages like:

> warning: operation on 'i' may be undefined

but the similar code:

```
if (l < left + middle &&
        (r == right || min == *(array + l)))
        *(buffer + i) = *(array + l++);
    else
        *(buffer + i) = *(array + r++);
```

did not result in warning messages. Note that all snippets are from the same project/file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment operator does not cause a sequence point.  This line, therefore:

```
    *(array + i + 1) = *(array + i--);
```

accesses/modifies `i` twice without an intervening sequence point.  That's the undefined behaviour you're being warned about.  The value you'll get for the `i` on the left side is not guaranteed by the language.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation. It really bugged me. I just wanted to skip writing additional brackets and --i line. Better do it anyway. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because you are both modifying `i` and accessing `i`'s prior value in another operand between [sequence points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point), for example here:

```
*(array + i) = *(buffer - left + i++);
          ^^                     ^^^
```

The draft C99 standard in section `6.5` *Expressions* paragraph *2* says:

> Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value
>   modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression.72) Furthermore, the **prior value
>   shall be read only to determine the value to be stored**.73)

and it gives the follows examples of undefined behavior in *footnote 73*:

```
i = ++i + 1;
^^  ^^^
a[i++] = i;
```

Note, the first example is similar the example pointed out from the code earlier.